# Substituting XML tags with LaTeX commands using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, latex

I need to convert an XML document to LaTeX. Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<foo>
    12345
    <bar>
        67890
    </bar>
</foo>
```

to

```
\foo{12345\bar{67890}}
```

If I do

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("foobar.xml") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'xml')

for tag in soup.find_all("foo"):
    tag.replaceWith(f"""{tag.text}""")
```

then it removes the tags inside. If I use `contents` instead of `text`, it returns a list.

I have tried `soup.find('foo').unwrap()`, but it just removes the tag, without replacing it.

I know I can first replace `bar` and then `foo`, but I would like a solution that doesn't depend on the order of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using recursion:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag


xml_doc = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    12345
    <bar>
        67890
    </bar>
</foo>"""


def write(tag):
    s = "\\" + tag.name + "{"
    for c in tag.contents:
        if isinstance(c, Tag):
            s += write(c)
        elif isinstance(c, NavigableString):
            s += c.strip()
    return s + "}"


soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")
print(write(soup.foo))
```

Prints:

```
\foo{12345\bar{67890}}
```

Comment: Is there a way to replace the contents of `soup` with the modified string?